# gem install refinerycms, Unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: rubygems, refinerycms

I'm trying to just install the refinerycms gem. This worked this morning:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
$ gem -v
2.0.3
$ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
https://rubygems.org/
$ gem install refinerycms
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires activesupport (= 3.2.13); activeresource requires activesupport (= 3.2.13), activemodel (= 3.2.13); globalize3 requires activemodel (>= 3.0.0); railties requires activesupport (= 3.2.13); actionpack requires activesupport (= 3.2.13), activemodel (= 3.2.13), builder (~> 3.0.0); activerecord requires activesupport (= 3.2.13), activemodel (= 3.2.13), arel (~> 3.0.2), tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the cause:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/6/25/Rails-4-0-final/

This is the solution (thanks to chriskk in #refinerycms on irc.freenode.net):

```
$ gem install rails -v 3.2.13
$ gem install refinerycms
```

Comment: Note, if you're getting errors referring to activesupport 4.0.0 or similar, after installing rails as above you'll need to remove all the 4.0.0 stuff. `gem uninstall activesupport activemodel ... etc etc ... rails -v 4.0.0`

Answer (score 4):

FYI, as of July 31 2013, you'll need to install rails -v 3.2.14, so:

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.14
gem install refinerycms
```