# Error: actionpack-4.0.2 requires active support (=4.0.2) but it conflicted. RoR/refinerycms

Tags: ruby, blogs, refinerycms, actionpack

I'm currently having trouble installing the blog-engine to my refineryCMS website. The error I'm having is following:

```
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::ImpossibleDependenciesError)
    actionpack-4.0.2 requires activesupport (= 4.0.2) but it conflicted: Activated     activesupport-4.0.2 instead of (= 3.2.16) via:
railties-3.2.16, refinerycms-core-2.1.1
```

Here's my gem   bundle:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.16)
  * actionpack (3.2.16)
  * activemodel (3.2.16)
  * activerecord (3.2.16)
  * activeresource (3.2.16)
  * activesupport (3.2.16)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1)
  * acts_as_indexed (0.8.3)
  * arel (3.0.3)
  * awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
  * babosa (0.3.11)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.0.3.0)
  * builder (3.0.4)
  * bundler (1.3.5)
  * capybara (2.1.0)
  * childprocess (0.3.9)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
  * columnize (0.3.6)
  * database_cleaner (1.2.0)
  * debugger (1.6.3)
  * debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
  * debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.4)
  * decorators (1.0.3)
  * devise (2.2.8)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * dragonfly (0.9.15)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.0.2)
  * factory_girl (4.2.0)
  * factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
  * ffi (1.9.3)
  * filters_spam (0.3)
  * friendly_id (4.0.10.1)
  * globalize (3.0.2)
  * globalize3 (0.3.0)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.9)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.3.0)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * mini_portile (0.5.2)
  * multi_json (1.8.2)
  * nokogiri (1.6.0)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * paper_trail (2.7.2)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.5)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (3.2.16)
  * rails-i18n (0.7.4)
  * rails_autolink (1.0.9)
  * railties (3.2.16)
  * rake (10.1.0)
  * rdoc (3.12.2)
  * refinerycms (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (1.0.0)
  * refinerycms-authentication (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-blog (2.1.0)
  * refinerycms-core (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-dashboard (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-i18n (2.1.0)
  * refinerycms-images (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-pages (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-resources (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-settings (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-testing (2.1.1)
  * routing-filter (0.3.1)
  * rspec-core (2.14.7)
  * rspec-expectations (2.14.4)
  * rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
  * rspec-rails (2.14.0)
  * rubyzip (0.9.9)
  * sass (3.2.12)
  * sass-rails (3.2.6)
  * selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
  * seo_meta (1.4.0)
  * sprockets (2.2.2)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.8)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * truncate_html (0.9.2)
  * tzinfo (0.3.38)
  * uglifier (2.3.2)
  * warden (1.2.3)
  * websocket (1.0.7)
  * will_paginate (3.0.5)
  * xpath (2.0.0)
```

I have tried updating, reinstalling bundle and removing 4.0.2 versions of activesupport, activeresource but didn't work. Because I've been fiddling around too much, even rails server doesn't work. Please help!!

Comment: What does your last working Gemfile look like?  What did you add to it to add the refinery blog gem?  Refinery doesn't currently support Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17310830/839849) SO post which suggest doing the following:

```
$ gem install rails -v 3.2.13
$ gem install refinerycms
```

I then added Rails 4